# Calculating the residue of $\frac{10z^4-10\sin(z)}{z^3}, z(0) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$\frac{10z^4-10\sin(z)}{z^3}, \quad z(0) = 0.$$

I've gotten that $$\operatorname{Res} = 0$$ but I'm not quite  sure if that is correct, or if I have even used a correct pathway towards it. How should one work around sine (or cosine, for that matter) during residue calculations?

Comment: Can you show us the pathway you chose so we can compare it with what we would do?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. The residue of a function is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ of the Laurent series expansion of the function.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[z^{-1}]}&\color{blue}{\frac{10z^4-10\sin z}{z^3}}\\
> &=[z^{-1}]\left(10z-\frac{10}{z^3}\left(z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots\right)\right)\\
> &=-10[z^{-1}]\left(\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{z^2}{5!}-\cdots\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

One way to work with sines and cosines in this problem is to reckon with their power series expansions found in many places, for instance [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-14/e/maclaurin-series-for-sin-x--cos-x--and-e-x&ved=2ahUKEwjM6Pig6qLeAhVE04MKHUocCQ0QFjAOegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2nSe49SxCx0219ywzwEmEW).  You might also note that an even function has only even powers in its Laurent series whereas the residue comes from the $(-1)$ power, therefore even functions will have a residue of zero.  Hmm, can you see why I would mention that last fact?